# Changing Matlab Nested Structures to Matrices Iteratively for histogram plotting

Tags: matlab, struct, statistics, histogram, cell-array

Pretty new to Matlab, so please forgive the poor coding. I have some data for different categories (9 categories) with a different number of data points in each category. I created a structure that holds the data points for the different categories. I believe the categories are themselves structures within the larger structure.

I want to plot a histogram for each category. The first thing I tried was just creating a for-loop and plotting a histogram for each category in the structure, but this failed because the histogram doesn't take in structures. The next thing I tried to do was create another for loop which would change the structure holding each category into a cell array, but this also failed with the error:

`if isnumeric(c{1}) || ischar(c{1}) || islogical(c{1}) || isstruct(c{1})`

I am able to individually change each category to a cell array and then to a matrix, which allowed me to create one histogram. Is there a way to do this using a loop? My code is below. Thanks.

```
data = readtable('');
data = table2array(data);
Trial = data(:,1);
dist = data(:,2);
Time = data(:,3);
intstim = data(:,4);
color = data(:,5);
UniqueDist = unique(dist);
for ii = 1.0:length(UniqueDist)
    idx = find(dist == UniqueDist(ii));
    distTime(ii).data = Time(idx);
    distTime(ii).data = distTime(ii).data(distTime(ii).data ~= 0);
end
for jj =1.0:length(distTime)
    distTime(jj).data = struct2cell(distTime(jj));
    distTime(jj).data = cell2mat(distTime(jj));
    
    
end
```

Comment: So you have your data in `distTime(ii).data`, and want to make a histogram for each `ii`? Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right, 9 histograms in total

Comment: But you already have that loop in place. Just add `histogram(distTime(ii).data)` to it and you're done. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Yes, I put that into the code, but I think it only generates one histogram which I think is either the first or last structure category of the nine categories

Comment: Maybe it plots each of the histograms to the same window? Try adding `figure` before the histogram command, inside the loop. You should then see 9 different figure windows.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you so much!